# BFS starting with a given node and reaching all nodes

Tags: c++, algorithm, graph, breadth-first-search

I have a scenario where

1. I want to run BFS starting at a particular node(let's say ID:7).
2. If there are nodes unreachable from this node, I want to restart the
   BFS(with any remaining node) until all vertices of the graph are
   visited.

What I have so far is code(partial) that starts from node 0 and restarts with another unvisited vertex:

```
void BFS()
{
    // Mark all the vertices as not visited
    bool *visited = new bool[V];
    for(int i = 0; i < V; i++)
        visited[i] = false;
    // Call the recursive function starting from all vertices one by one
    for(int i = 0; i < V; i++)
        if(visited[i] = = false)
            BFSUtil(i,visited);
}

void BFSUtil(int s,bool *visited)
{
    queue<int> queue;
    visited[s]=true;
    queue.push(s);

    while(!queue.empty())
    {
        s = queue.front();
        queue.pop();
         // Get all adjacent vertices of the dequeued vertex s
        // If a adjacent has not been visited, then mark it visited
        // and enqueue it
        for(i = adj[s].begin(); i != adj[s].end(); ++i)
        {
            if(!visited[i])
            {                
                queue.push(i);
                BFSUtil(id,visited);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

How do I efficiently change this code to suit my requirement?

Answer (score 0):

You have most of the ideas in place already since you're storing this `visited` state and have #1 down. To do #2, you can simply iterate through the `visited` list looking for a value of false to indicate an unvisited node. Now run #1 on that one. Repeat until you find that all entries in `visited` are true.

Something like this:

```
// Loop until all elements have been visited.
bool found = false;
do
{
    // Look for an element that hasn't been processed yet
    // to run the BFS.
    found = false;
    for(int i = 0; i < V; i++)
    {
        if(visited[i] = = false)
        {
            BFSUtil(i,visited);    
            found = true;
        }
    }
} while (found);
```

You could also avoid the linear search through `visited` each time after #1 with a more efficient set than a bunch of booleans you have to linearly search through, but probably the effort required isn't worth the effort unless you're searching a whole bunch of teeny, disconnected graphs, and that would normally degrade the performance of the traversal unless it was a really efficient set (or a dense + sparse one: one for constant-time quick checks, another with log or better time insertion).